# How to generate a matrix with a function pattern?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, function, math, matrix

**Background info** (Optional reading):

I'm running simulations of reflections of sound waves in against boundaries. The medium conditions for the points in space are set using a matrix. Let's say the dimensions of the space is an `N` by `N` grid, and there are two speeds of sound I care about, `c0` and `c1`.

Right now I'm using code like the following to generate barrier patterns

```
medium.sound_speed = c0*ones(N,N);   % set the speed of sound to be c0 everywhere
medium.sound_speed(:, N/2:N) = c1;   % set the right half of the grid to a different speed
medium.sound_speed(50:70, 50:70) = c1; % set a box to have a different speed
```

Or

```
% set all speeds to c0 except set the diagonal to c1
medium.sound_speed = c0*ones(N,N)-(c0*eye(N,N))+c1*eye(N,N);
```

However, I can't generate more complex boundaries with different curvatures.

**Question**

I want to programmatically create matrices with patterns reflecting functions. For instance, I want to enter `f(x)=2` and for that to create a matrix that looked something like this, assuming `N=6`.

```
[ 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 
  1 1 1 1 1 1 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

Or `f(x)=0.5*x+1`

```
[ 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1
  0 0 1 1 0 0 
  1 1 0 0 0 0 
  0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

I would also be able to generate curved patterns like `f(x)=1/x`, which seems to require some form of the [Midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm), used for drawing curvatures with pixels.

```
[ 1 0 0 0 0 0
  1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 1  
  0 0 0 0 0 0 ]
```

In reality, `N` is at least 128, so manually creating these matrices for shapes with some level of complexity is impractical, and I thought this was an interesting problem.

Does anyone know of some way to do this, or suggestions for alternative approaches?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:** 
I modified [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25544-line-drawing-by-bresenham-algorithm/content/bresenham_line.m) implementation of Bresenham's algorithm to provide a matrix with the desired line given an origin and an ending point.

```
function M=bresenham_line(point)

if (abs(point(4)-point(2)) > abs(point(3)-point(1)))       % If the line is steep                                
    x0 = point(2);y0 = point(1); x1 = point(4);y1=point(3);% then it would be converted to 
    token =1;                                              % non steep by changing coordinate
else
    x0 = point(1);y0 = point(2); x1 = point(3);y1=point(4);
    token = 0; 
end
if(x0 >x1)
    temp1 = x0; x0 = x1; x1 = temp1;
    temp2 = y0; y0 = y1; y1 = temp2;
end
dx = abs(x1 - x0) ;                              % Distance to travel in x-direction
dy = abs(y1 - y0);                               % Distance to travel in y-direction
sx = sign(x1 - x0);                              % sx indicates direction of travel in X-dir
sy = sign(y1 - y0);                              % Ensures positive slope line

x = x0; y = y0;                                  % Initialization of line
param = 2*dy - dx ;                              % Initialization of error parameter
for i = 0:dx-1                                   % FOR loop to travel along X
    x_coord(i+1) = x;                            % Saving in matrix form for plot
    y_coord(i+1) = y;

    param = param + 2*dy;                        % parameter value is modified
    if (param >0)                                % if parameter value is exceeded
        y = y +1*sy;                             % then y coordinate is increased
        param = param - 2*(dx );                 % and parameter value is decreased

    end
    x = x + 1*sx;                                % X-coordinate is increased for next point
end

M = zeros(size(x_coord,2), size(y_coord,2));

for i=1:1:size(x_coord,2)
    x = x_coord(i);
    y = y_coord(i);

    M(x,y) = 1;
end

M
```

Implemented like so:

```
c1 = 0;
M = bresenham_line([1 1 Nx/2+1 Ny+1]);
medium.sound_speed = c0*ones(Nx,Ny) - (c0*M) + c1*M;
```

No progress on curved function shapes yet.

Comment: This question is getting close votes for being off-topic as a "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource", which I don't think it is. Can someone clarify? This seems like quite a specific question with examples of an output given a specific input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to get some similar results:

```
f = @(x)0.5*x; %create the function (x should be written even if the function doesn't depend on x: @(x) 0*x + 2)
N = 6; %choose the size of the atrix
M = zeros(N,N); %create an empty matrix
x = (1:N); 
y = round(f(x-1)); %discretization
x(y>N-1|y<0) = [];
y(y>N-1|y<0) = [];
M(sub2ind(size(M),y+1,x)) = 1;
M = flipud(M)
```

So you can choose your function, then the result in your matrix will look like a discretization of a normal `plot`.

Comment: Thanks! This works. The only problem is that I need to increase the width of the function band so that there aren't holes in it when the angle is steep.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly 'dirty' way of getting something like this, although I you best bet might Bresenham's algorithm.

```
N = 128;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:N);
bound1 = Y<2*X;
bound2 = Y<2*X+1;
M = xor(bound1,bound2);
```

`bound1` you can define any function `y=f(x)`, and mark the area under it. with `bound2` you select and area that is slightly higher (shifted up). Once you take and `xor` of the two area you get just the desired `y=f(x)` marked. I think that in order to get reasonable results the shift might be different for more complicated function.

For illustration I used `imagesc` (the `flipud` is just for make the `(0,0)` in the bottom left, instead of the top left):

```
imagesc(flipud(M));
```

---

**Edit**

Indeed for some function this might not be the best. For example for `y=x^2`, you have to increase the shift and still does not look great.

```
bound1 = Y<X.^2;
bound2 = Y<X.^2+15;
M = xor(bound1,bound2);
```